# Can a customer without a PayPal account still pay for recurring payments with a credit card

Tags: php, curl

i have to make recurring payment without making login on pay pal and pay via credit and debit card.
i follow the following sample codes but they are not helpfull - 
https://github.com/hrendoh/PayPal-Recurring-Payment-example

Comment: what is the code that you have tried? In wich part you getting errors?

Comment: I'm afraid this question isn't very helpful either.  If you can describe specifically what you've tried and where you're stuck, we can probably help with that.  But all you've given us is your project requirement.  Stack Overflow doesn't write your project for you.

Comment: i want to make recurring payment by the customer without redirect to paypal account what it is happened in paypal

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that you can't do that in Express Checkout with Recurring Payment because Express Checkout with Recurring Payment only uses PayPal as the funding source.

see here https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/express-checkout/ht_ec-recurringPaymentProfile-curl-etc/

Comment: i want to receive payment on paypal merchant account with accepting reccuring payment by the customer on my website without redirect to paypal what it is possible in paypal

Comment: You can use DPRP (Direct Payment Recurring Payment) but that requires Pro account in US or Canada

Comment: i am using DPRP method it gives "DPRP is disabled for this merchant" error for my sandbox account. i already upgrade my business account to my business-pro account but still i found that error how is i resolve this

Comment: this required a setting from the back-end of the account. As for this I strongly suggest you contact PayPal MTS. They could help toggling the setting in Sandbox account.